# Regex for valid domain names

Tags: regex

I'am having some problems creating a regex to allow the only valid domain names.
The rules are:

- It has 3 characters minimum.
- Can have dots but can't have two in a row. Can't have another special characters
- Can have lower and upper case letters and numbers
- Between points, it needs to have at least one character

For example:

Valid domain name -> bruno.cCm.pt3

Invalid domain name -> bruno..com (or) bruno.

What I have right now is this: `^.{2,253}([A-Za-z\d](-*[A-Za-z\d])*)(\.([A-Za-z\d](-*[A-Za-z\d])*))*$`

Comment: Try `^\w+(?:\.\w+)+$`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one, i made some test and i think it solves your problem:

> (?:a-z0-9?.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]

Should also help you in extracting domain names from more complex strings.

This one should also manage upper/lower case:

> (?:a-zA-Z0-9?.)+[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: Tried with RegExr and seems to work: https://regexr.com/3au3g. Maybe it is not strictly related to domain names, but should do the work

Comment: Works on your examples by just lowering cases. Now you have to manage lower/upper case situation.